# Google pay transaction declined: invalid payment method. [or_ccreu_01]

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, payment-gateway, google-pay

i am trying to use google pay in my app, everything is all set but, My Mastercard is not saving, or even add to my Card. I am try but i cant see a working solution about this..

this is the Images getting
[image]
[image]
just confuse on how to solve this.

Comment: Have you ON Online International Transactions ?

Comment: how can i on it ?

Comment: Contact your bank

Answer (score 0):

You need to forcefully convert your amount into a string as my amount was already a string so I decided not to convert it into a string. But that was the problem you have to convert it into a string

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  paymentItems.add(
      PaymentItem(

        amount: widget.totalAmount.toString(),

        label: 'Total Amount',
        status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
     ),
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar error. I got the solution from a comment by @MehulGohil.

This error was coming because **International Transactions** was not enabled in my credit card.

So I used another credit card in which **International Transaction** was enabled, and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue from last 15 days ! I had tried with VISA and MASTER card with enabled International transaction but unfortunately None of those worked. I was getting error like currency-problem/transaction decline/invalid info...

Finally Today I have bought my google play console of $25 using same my Paytm VISA card which I was using earlier.

It was happening because once I had attached payment method to google Admob (OR In your case you may have done something else).

Once follow these Step to resolve your payment problem-

1. Go to https://payments.google.com/gp/w/home/paymentmethods
2. Delete all the payment method whatever is there.
3. Make sure International transaction is enable for your card.
4. Now do the payment !
   (I had used the same Paytm VISA debit card)

[Make Sure International uses is enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD2Gj.jpg) 
Now try to pay, I hope it will work for you too.

I hope Now I will be able to put my SHER App on google Playstore

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**GOOGLE PLAY** : I solved it by creating a new developer account, not using my email name but my company credentials (Its simply, it asks you if you want to create a payment account different than your own email account. It seems that old card info, and other data gets in a way. Also my bank allowed international transactions and purchases, but there is an important new issue I did not know : CVV (Credit or Debit Card Security Number) changes every 5 minutes as an aditional security measure of my cards. It updates in my bank app and I was using the one printed in the back of the card. Be careful with that, google can also block you after many failures.